# How to get the color of pixels on mapbox

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have radar raster on my map and i want to show the data color of the radar by the position of the cursor.

[An example of a radar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9EWC.png)

I'm trying to get context of a mapbox canvas by `map.getCanvas().getContext('2d')` but it returns null.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: from what I understand, this is unfortunately not possible / supported right now -- here is the [open github issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1404) on this topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain the canvas context (webgl) this way and inspect colors.

```js
map.on("mousemove", e => {
  const canvas = map.getCanvas();
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('webgl2');
  if (gl) {
    const { point } = e;
    const { x, y } = point;
    const data = new Uint8Array(4);
    const canvasX = x - canvas.offsetLeft;
    const canvasY = canvas.height - y - canvas.offsetTop;
    gl.readPixels(canvasX, canvasY, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    const [r, g, b, a] = data;
    const color = `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${a})`;
    console.log(`Color at (${x}, ${y}) = ${color}`);
  }
});
```

I had to set map option `preserveDrawingBuffer` to `true` to be able to get pixel values.

```js
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: "map",
  style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10",
  zoom: 4,
  center: [77.209, 28.6139],
  preserveDrawingBuffer: true
});
```

This codepen implements a simple color inspector: https://codepen.io/manishraj/full/jONzpzL

Comment: The codepen doesn't quite work... when I hover over the water, I get red/peach colors like the land.

Answer (score 3):

**Use GL buffer's location rather than mouse's screen coordinates.**

As mentioned in the comment on Manish's very good answer, the codepen is not working because it is using the mouse location while it should use the location on the WebGL buffer, as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.3.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.3.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>

    <style>
        #map canvas {
            cursor: crosshair;
        }
    </style>

    
    <body>
    <div
      id="map"
      style="position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 100%;">
    </div>

    <div
      id="colorPicker"
      style="height:30px; width:30px; position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 30px; z-index: 999;
      border: 3px solid white;">
    </div>

    <script>

      mapboxgl.accessToken =
        "pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4M29iazA2Z2gycXA4N2pmbDZmangifQ.-g_vE53SD2WrJ6tFX7QHmA";
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: "map",
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9',
        zoom: 4,
        center: [77.209, 28.6139],
        preserveDrawingBuffer: true
      });
      window.map = map;
      map.on("load", () => {
        const colorStyle = document.getElementById("colorPicker").style;
        map.on("click", e => {
          const canvas = map.getCanvas();
          const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("webgl2");

          if (gl) {
            const data = new Uint8Array(4);
                        
                        // Canvas width and hwight is what you see on the screen
                        const canvasWidth = parseFloat(canvas.style.width, 10);
                        const canvasHeight = parseFloat(canvas.style.height, 10);

                        // e.point.x and y, specifying the horizontal and vertical pixels read from the lower left corner of the screen
                        canvasX = e.point.x;
                        canvasY = e.point.y;

                        // WenGL buffer is larger than canvas, there 
            const bufferX = (gl.drawingBufferWidth / canvasWidth * canvasX).toFixed(0);
            const bufferY = (gl.drawingBufferHeight / canvasHeight * (canvasHeight - canvasY)).toFixed(0);

            gl.readPixels(
              bufferX,
              bufferY,
              1,
              1,
              gl.RGBA,
              gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
              data
            );
            const [r, g, b, a] = data;
            const color = `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${a})`;
            colorStyle.backgroundColor = color;

                        console.log (`Canvas size (w/h): ${canvasWidth}/${canvasHeight}`);
                        console.log (`Buffer size (w/h): ${gl.drawingBufferWidth}/${gl.drawingBufferHeight}`);
                        console.log (`Point on Canvas (x/y): ${canvasX}/${canvasY}`);
                        console.log (`Point on Buffer (x/y): ${bufferX}/${bufferY}`);
                        console.log (`Color: ${color}`);
          }
        });
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Get some trouble to get the correct coordinates with mobile devices and different device pixel ratio
https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-picking.html

doesn't seem needed to use drawingBuffer