# How to find the rgb color of pixel under mouse hover in MapboxGL Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webgl, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I would like to get the exact color in rgb of the pixel under mouse hover in MapboxGL Js.
What can be the best possible way to get this done ?

Comment: Be more specific on what you really want. Thanks.

Comment: I just want to show the value on mouse move on a colored Image Layer. For this I have been given Color Legends with value defined for color. For this, I want to pick the rgb color under the mouse move and match that pixel color with legends to get the required value.

Comment: is there any clue regarding the same?

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735470/get-pixel-color-from-canvas-on-mouseover?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the RGB color of the pixel being hovered over in a Mapbox GL JS map, you can get the WebGL canvas context and use the [`WebGLRenderingContext.readPixels` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/readPixels) to obtain each of the four `RGBA` values.

This code can be executed when the [`mousemove` map event](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map.event:mousemove) is fired, as shown in the below code snippet from the answer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57862383/how-to-get-the-color-of-pixels-on-mapbox):

```
map.on("mousemove", e => {
  const canvas = map.getCanvas();
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('webgl2');
  if (gl) {
    const { point } = e;
    const { x, y } = point;
    const data = new Uint8Array(4);
    const canvasX = x - canvas.offsetLeft;
    const canvasY = canvas.height - y - canvas.offsetTop;
    gl.readPixels(canvasX, canvasY, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    const [r, g, b, a] = data;
    const color = `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${a})`;
    console.log(`Color at (${x}, ${y}) = ${color}`);
  }
});
```

As also noted in the linked SO post, [the map's `preserveDrawingBuffer` parameter](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map) must be set to `true`, as shown below. The parameter is set to `false` by default as a performance optimization.

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // stylesheet location
    center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 9, // starting zoom
    preserveDrawingBuffer: true // preserve the buffer where fragment colors are written, comes with a performance cost
});
```

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ux9pke34/) demonstrates the above functionality, along with an HTML element displaying the retrieved RGBA values. You can run the example by replacing `/* ADD YOUR MAPBOX ACCESS TOKEN HERE */` with your own Mapbox access token.